# PHP Session variables disappearing on 'POST'

Tags: php, html, session-variables

I boiled my script down as simple as possible to illustrate the trouble I described above.

Here is testPage1.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
?>
<form action="testPage2.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="See vars" />
</form>
```

And here is testPage2.php

```
<?php 
    echo 'session variables:<br />';
    Print_r ($_SESSION); 
?>
```

Expected output in the browser for testPage2 would be:
**session variables:

Array ( [loggedIn] => 1 )**
Instead, i just get
**session variables:**
Checking /var/log/apache2/error.log reveals
*[Mon Jul 08 22:00:25 2013] [error] [client 155.70.23.19] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: _SESSION in /var/www/euler/testPage2.php on line 3, referer: http://myURL.net/euler/testPage1.php*
Any Ideas?

Comment: put session_start() on every page

Comment: `session_start()` on testPage2.php

Comment: page2 is missing  session_start()

Comment: Okay, I see that adding that to the page will remedy the situation.  Now, I already have a head.php page like this: `<?php 
 session_start();
?>`
any idea why using "`include head.php;`" at the top of testPage2.php doesn't remedy the situation?  I'd like to not have to add session_start to every page since I've already included that header page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

testPage2.php is missing session_start(); add

```
session_start();
```

on the top of testPage2.php

Comment: Okay, I see that adding that to the page will remedy the situation.  Now, I already have a head.php page like this: `<?php 
 session_start();
?>`
any idea why using "`include head.php;`" at the top of testPage2.php doesn't remedy the situation?  I'd like to not have to add session_start to every page since I've already included that header page.

Comment: are you literally using `include head.php;` or `include('head.php'); ` ?

Comment: literally using `include 'head.php';`

Answer (score 2):

From the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

So include `session_start()` at the very top in every php script you will use sessions in.